# Finite expected value implies sublinear maximum expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was recently presented with the following question. Let $X_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|] < \infty$. We then have that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}\left[ \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |X_k|\right] = 0$$
My first idea was using Kolmogorov Maximal Inequality in some way, but I notice that this requires a finite variance. So any ideas on how I should approach this?

Comment: You should distinguish between $EX_i <\infty$ and $E|X_i| <\infty$. This quesiton has been answered many times on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(t) = \mathbb{P}( |X_1| > t) $

We have:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}( \max_{1\le k \le n} |X_k|)& \stackrel{(1)}{=} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}( \max_{1 \le k \le n } |X_k| >t)dt =\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ 1-\mathbb{P}( \max_{1 \le k \le n } |X_k| \le t) \right]dt
\\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ 1- \big(1-g(t) \big)^n }{n}dt \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow +\infty]{(2)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \left[\frac{ 1- \big(1-g(t) \big)^n }{n}\right]dt
\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} 0.dt=0
\end{align} 
$$

where in (2) we have use the DCT theorem with two facts that $ 0 \le \frac{1-(1-g(t))^n}{n} \le g(t)$ for all $n$ and that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)dt = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_1|>t)dt \stackrel{(3)}{=} \mathbb{E}(|X_1|)$$
, and in (1) and (3) we have employed the following useful equality:

**Lemma** If $Y$ is an integrable nonnegative random variable then
$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y>t)dt$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Lovely solution. Just a small question, the inequality that you used in (2) was Bernoulli Inequality right?

Comment: @JohannMartens  Yeah, it was.